# Swift Actor thread safety with continuations

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, actor

I am reading about actors and as a teaching example I am rewriting an old piece of code which used delegation to use async await. I am using checked continuations to interface the sync to async.

I read this introduction: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swift-actors/ As I understand, since the actors are re-entrant we need to keep track of the work that's currently being performed - i.e. the active task.

What I am not sure about is how this marries together with continuations.

Here's my code. Thanks for the help!

```
public actor MyNewDelegateSub {
    
    
    private var activeTask: Task<BLEDevice, Error>?
    private var checkedThrowingContinuation: CheckedContinuation<BLEDevice, Error>?
    private var bleDelegate: BluetoothLEDelegate
    
    
    public func returnFunctionThatReplacesDelegateCallbacks() async throws -> BLEDevice? {
        if let existingTask = activeTask {
            return try await existingTask.value
        }
        
        let task = Task<BLEDevice?, Error> {
            return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation({ [weak self] (continuation: CheckedContinuation<BLEDevice, Error>) in
                bleDelegate.checkedThrowingContinuation = continuation
                do{
                    bleDelegate.scan()
                    activeTask = nil
                } catch {
                   activeTask = nil
                   throw error
            })
        }
        activeTask = task
        return try await task.value
    }
}

private final class BluetoothLEDelegate: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    
    private let centralManager = CBCentralManager()
    var checkedThrowingContinuation: CheckedContinuation<BLEDevice, Error>?
    
    init() {
        centralManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        checkedThrowingContinuation?.resume(returning: BLEDevice(peripheral) )
        checkedThrowingContinuation = nil
       }
    ....
}
```

Comment: So what issue are you currently having with the code you've included in your question? Does it not compile? Does it produce warnings? Does it not work as expected?

Comment: @DávidPásztor it works from what I can tell and compiles, my question was is it ok to use checkedThrowingContinuation as a return from a Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable to use `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` in a `Task`.

---

That having been said, there are a bunch of issues with this code snippet, though:

1. In your `do`-`try`-`catch`, there is no `try`. Thus there is nothing to ever `catch`. Also, you wouldn’t `throw` from inside a `withCheckedThrowingContinuation`, anyway, you would `resume` with the error.
2. Whenever you use [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency), such as `Task {…}`, you are responsible for writing your own cancelation handling code, e.g. [`withTaskCancellationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withtaskcancellationhandler(operation:oncancel:)/).
3. In a more stylistic observation, but rather than passing the continuation to the bluetooth manager object (which entangles these two types together, introduces non-local reasoning about the continuation which practically invites its eventual misuse, etc.), I might advise that you decouple these two types:

   - give the bluetooth manager object closure properties associated with the relevant delegate methods, and have the delegate methods call those closures … now the bluetooth manager is no longer tightly-coupled with the continuation code; and
   - inside the `withCheckedThrowingContinuation`, spin up the bluetooth manager, set its closures, and inside those closures, `resume` and cleanup as needed.
4. The right pattern for discover of bluetooth devices is probably an `AsyncSequence`, e.g., an `AsyncStream`, anyway, not a task. See WWDC 2021 video [Meet AsyncSequence](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10058/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough and helpful answer Rob!